# Or condition in filter

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to write a simple or condition in a filter like the following?:

```
formResponse in formResponses | filter: { formName: form } || filter:{ formCategory: formCategory }"
```

I know that the syntax is wrong but logically something similar. So if formCategory is set, it would filter by that and not formName, if formName is set it would filter by that and not formCategory. Right now it works as an and condition so it will filter by formName and formCategory.

Comment: You can create your own custom filter that takes both parameters and in that filter decide how you want to filter the items based n the parameters

Comment: @Aidin thanks. I really need to get better at doing custom filters.

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

```
formResponse in formResponses | customFilter: filter
```

Implementation:

```
angular.module('customFilter', [])
.filter('customFilter', [function () {
    'use strict';

return function (items, filter) {
    var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
            if (filter.formName}
                   .....
            if (filter.formCategory)
                   ....
            if (passes filter criteria)
                  filtered.push(value);

        });
    }

    return filtered;
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following:

```
<span ng-click="category='clinical'; name=''">Clinical Docs</span>
<span ng-click="name='intake'; category=''">Intake</span>

<div ng-repeat='formResponse in formResponses | filter: { formName: name } | filter: { formCategory: category }
```